# Which I/O block size do I need for direct I/O?

Tags: linux, file-io

I am working a project where I need to use direct I/O on a linux system.  (If you have a distaste for it, well, I just have to.  There's not alot I can do about it.)  So I need to know the I/O block size of the system.  From what I have read on the web, the result given by the `stat` command seems to be preferred.  I get

```
$ stat -f .
  File: "."
    ID: 0        Namelen: 255     Type: nfs
Block size: 65536      Fundamental block size: 65536
Blocks: Total: 135132688  Free: 26644679   Available: 26644679
Inodes: Total: 29999901   Free: 7214433
```

So the block size seems to be 65536 bytes or 64kB.

However, if I look at the file sizes reported by `du`, I see things like

```
$ du --block-size=1 ./*
8192    ./diffs
4096    ./Makefile
4096    ./foo
8192    ./bar
4096    ./ni
4096    ./pwn
20480   ./.git/refs
4096    ./.git/branches
```

Clearly all file sizes are multiples of the more standard 4096 bytes, which would indicate that 4096 is the real block size.  People writing on this subject seem to think that the block size determined from these two methods will be the same.  Why is it not?  Which size is appropriate for direct I/O?

Comment: Since you should not be trying to match the direct i/o buffer size to the underlying hardware block size (which by the way you can't access anyways since you're using NFS), "what is the FS block size?" and "what size is appropriate for direct i/o?" are two different questions. Which one are you interested in?

Comment: OK.  Seems like I have been told wrong or misunderstood what I have been told.  What I really need is the size appropriate for direct I/O.

Comment: That's up to your application's access pattern. Just try to align the start and end of it.

Comment: Normally files systems exist on top of block devices. The issue is NFS is not a block device, it a file system abstraction (Network File System). So you will be unable to do block operations to a NFS. If you require a network block device, there is samba. Samba provodes a network block device abstraction

Comment: There is no point to do this unless your NFS is mounted sync. If it is, be aware that I/O will be slow. Using O_DIRECT on aligned 4k buffers will not make it much worse, it is just a hint to bypass cache where possible.